# how to create setup file dynamically

Tags: .net, deployment, installation

can you tell me how to create setup file dynamically in c#.net or VB.Net.

Please reply me soon

Samir

Answer (score 2):

Windows Installer databases (such as msi files) can be manipulated with the **Deployment Tools Foundation** (also known as "DTF") libraries. These libraries are part of the [wix project](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).

If you have wix 3.0 installed, you can find the DTF assemblies in `C:\program files\Windows Installer XML v3\sdk`.

The documentation can be found in `C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3\doc\` in the files `dtf.chm` and `dtfapi.chm`.

Comment: can you give me an example how to use dtf?

Comment: @Samir: that's what the API documentation is for. Read the docs, play around with the API and come back if you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the Windows Installer SDK, which is part of the Windows SDK or Windows Platform SDK depending on the Windows Installer version you are targeting.

http://blogs.msdn.com/windows_installer_team/archive/2009/08/12/latest-sdk-for-windows-installer-5-0.aspx

Depending on your setup requirements, you might also want to check out a script-based installer such as Inno Setup or nsis which might be easier to create dynamically.